# upload the file by using path

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, file-upload

Is it possible upload file through jsp.

```
var filepathhere = "http:// xxxx.com/--------/upliaded.pdf".
```

for exm: `http:// xxxxx/test.jsp?file = filepathhere.`

can i uses like this, is it possible to by using the path we can upload this.

Answer (score 0):

1. Accept URL from user in HTML form.
2. `POST` URL to servlet , try to read File from passed `URL` check its type and other validations.
3. Read file from that URL and on write or insert it in to your own `DB`

   - [File Upload and Download using Java](http://www.javabeat.net/tips/36-file-upload-and-download-using-java.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. `request.getParameter("file")` return `Object` that you can cast it to `String` and can download from that `URL`

something like that :

```
String file= (String) request.getParameter("file");
URL fileUrl = new URL(file);
```

and can  download from here

Answer (score 0):

You can get the information in the format of string doing it this way but I don't think you can get any other format( like pdf in your example) of data directly from the url. You can off course first download the file to some path and then get it from there.